# Electron Spotify not opening in desktop mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Electron is not opening spotify in desktop mode, as you can see in the screenshot below.
Here is the code:

```js
const {BrowserWindow, app} = require("electron");
const pie = require("puppeteer-in-electron")
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const main = async () => {
    const cookiesPath = path.join(__dirname, "cookies/open.spotify.com.cookies.json");
 const cookies = JSON.parse(await fs.readFileSync(cookiesPath, 'utf8'));
  await pie.initialize(app);
  const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer);
 
  const window = new BrowserWindow();
  const url = "https://example.com/";
  await window.loadURL(url);
 
  const page = await pie.getPage(browser, window);
  await page.goto("https://open.spotify.com");
  for (const cookie of cookies) {
    if (cookie.name !== 'ig_lang') {
await page.setCookie(cookie);
}
  }
await page.reload();
};

main();
```

Note I'm using puppeteer-in-electron so that I can automate web process even in electron.
But, this is not an issue because even if I use electron normally without puppeteer the issue persists.

This is how it should've been: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1026704902925324410/1026710664611377202/unknown.png

This is how it is: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1026704902925324410/1026704903055343626/Screenshot_42.png

Hope I've explained it well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install package `"https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases#v20.0.0+wvcus"` 
 
like this: 
`npm install "https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases#v20.0.0+wvcus" --save-dev` 
 
import also components

```
const { BrowserWindow, app, components } = require("electron");
```

to open in desktop mode just add userAgent:

```
window.loadURL(url, {
    userAgent: "Chrome/105.0.0.0",
});
```

and create BrowserWindow after app and components are ready

```
app.whenReady().then(async () => {
    await components.whenReady();
    main();
});
```

full code:

```
const { BrowserWindow, app, components } = require("electron");
const pie = require("puppeteer-in-electron");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

pie.initialize(app);

const main = async () => {
    const cookiesPath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        "cookies/open.spotify.com.cookies.json",
    );
    const cookies = JSON.parse(await fs.readFileSync(cookiesPath, "utf8"));
   
    const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer);

    const window = new BrowserWindow();
    const url = "https://example.com/";
    await window.loadURL(url, {
        userAgent: "Chrome/105.0.0.0",
    });

    const page = await pie.getPage(browser, window);
    await page.goto("https://open.spotify.com");
    for (const cookie of cookies) {
        if (cookie.name !== "ig_lang") {
            await page.setCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    await page.reload();
};

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
    await components.whenReady()
    main();
});
```

short version of code:

```
const { BrowserWindow, app, components } = require("electron");

const main = () => {
    const window = new BrowserWindow();
    const url = "https://open.spotify.com";
    window.loadURL(url, {
        userAgent: "Chrome/105.0.0.0",
    });
};

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
    await components.whenReady();
    main();
});
```

Comment: Well uh it's like desktop but it does not actually not working... This is what it shows:
"Enable secure playback in your browser
Visit the Spotify support site to see how."

With a button including link: https://support.spotify.com/ca-en/article/web-player-help
What do I do now?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: go here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_nav_useragent and copy output inside it window.webContents.setUserAgent(...here...);

Comment: Same. But I think we need to do this:
1) In your browser address bar, enter chrome://settings/content
2) Under Protected content, switch on Allow site to play protected content.
How to do it in electron though?

Comment: no. I think I figured it out.

Comment: It's the same...

Comment: ok. I have solution

Comment: well it worked but now it's playing random songs one by one I can't even pause the song it just goes to another what's the problem :P

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to fix it. if it is at all possible to fix.

Comment: Should I edit the post fully like change the title and stuff to "Spotify playing random songs in electron" ? Would that be helpful?

Comment: then my answer won't make sense and it might be helpful to someone

Comment: maybe create new question

Comment: oh ok I will all good, thanks for the answer. I will accept the answer as it helped the most.